# Why am I getting uninitialized constant for mailer after generating mailer?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailer

building a rails 6 app. I added a mailer using the command

```
rails generate mailer NotificationMailer
```

and I have this in my app/mailers/application_mailer.rb

```html
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

and this in my notification_mailer.rb

```html
class NotificationMailer < ApplicationMailer

    default from: "no-reply@****app.com"

    def comment_added
         mail(to: "****@gmail.com",
         subject: "A comment has been added to your place")
    end

end
```

but when I try to test the mailer in the console with this command

```
NotificationMailer.comment_added.deliver
```

I get a NameError- Uninitialized Constant NotificationMailer

Anybody know what I'm missing to get this to work?

Comment: the command should mail ( ) do ... |format| and then you can specify the format, check this link  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#create-a-mailer-view for sample format

Comment: Did you restart your `rails console` after the `generate` command? You can also run the command `reload!`
I just did what you have written and the error that I get is not this but `ActionView::MissingTemplate` which is the correct error.

Comment: thanks i thought i had restarted the console but i hadn't run reload!

Comment: @greg I have posted the comment as an answer with more information if it helped you solve the problem do consider accepting it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your `rails console` after the `generate` command?

You can also run the command `reload!`. This command will allow you to make changes to your code, and continue to use the same console session without having to restart

Comment: I have a similar problem with my `UserMailer`. Have tried closing and opening the `rails console` and use `reload!` but it did not work. `UserMailer` works when I am using `pry` in `rails s` There is no issues with calling `ApplicationMailer` though.